# Where does regiment and ships reinforce from?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Suppose I make a regiment and a ship in Roma. My territory is the whole Italian peninsula.

If that regiment and ship suffered casualties. Does the reinforcement comes from Roma only? Or does it come from the global manpower and sailor pool, which means it doesn't matter where you build the units?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from the global pools.
With the exception of the reinforcement bonus who comes from thin air.
(if you had 20 % reinforcement bonus, only 100 unit will be removed from the pool but 120 will be reinforced).